# fabric keyword argument error

Tags: fabric

I'm running fabric to deploy my django app.  I'm issuing the following command:

```
run('cd $(path); mkdir releases; mkdir shared; mkdir packages;', fail='ignore')
```

but i get an error for this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/fabric/main.py", line 419, in main
    commands[name](*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/davidh/django/fabfile.py", line 34, in setup
    run('cd $(path); mkdir releases; mkdir shared; mkdir packages;', fail='ignore')
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/fabric/network.py", line 382, in host_prompting_wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: run() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fail'
```

any ideas?  do i need to import something extra for using 'fail'? thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`run` doesn't take a fail command: http://docs.fabfile.org/0.9.3/api/core/operations.html#fabric.operations.run

Perhaps you mean `with settings(warn_only=True):`: http://docs.fabfile.org/0.9.3/api/core/context_managers.html#fabric.context_managers.settings